# Exception for a blank text box

Tags: exception

I am trying to make an exception where an error message pops up saying

> Error: Amount is required

when they haven't added the amount in the box. Here is what I have:

```
String output = "Gas Amount: $" + gasAmount +
                      "\nCar Wash: " + price;
  try {
      throw new AmountException();
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
  } 
  catch (AmountException ae) {
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ae.toString(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);      
  }
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
public class AmountException extends Throwable
{
  public AmountException()
  {
    super("Error: Amount is required!!");
  }
}
```

In your code:

```
try
{
  if (gasAmount == null)
    throw new AmountException();
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, output);
}
catch (AmountException ae)
{
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ae.getMessage(), "Error", JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
}
```

Comment: I did add that to my code but now my error message will not pop up.

Comment: Are you sure your 'gasAmount' equals null? Is it an instance of a Number class or a primitive type? Maybe it equals 0...